# "Double" evaluation in PHP

Tags: php, variables, evaluation

Morning all!

My MySQL query returns a PHP variable name which I'd like to "double" evaluate when I output it.  It may be best for me to do this by example.

On the static resources page I have:

```
$page1 = "test1.php";
$page2 = "test2.php";
```

And my MySQL table called tbl_pages contains 2 entries under fld_pagename: $page1 and $page2.  That way, I figure that I only define $page1 and $page2 once.

Now, on the page I'm working on, I have a query which returns the name of the page:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT fld_pagename FROM tbl_pages WHERE fld_show = 1 ORDER BY fld_ref");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $nameofpage = $row['fld_pagename'];
    echo "$nameofpage",'<br />';
}
```

However, the double quotes around the variable only evaluate the variable to one level.  Its output is:

```
$page1<br />$page2<br />
```

But I want these variables to be evaluated before output:

```
test1.php<br />test2.php<br />
```

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: `echo $nameofpage.'<br/>';` ? [test here](http://codepad.org/j0nlbG1p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you can use this PHP feature (example):

```
$test1=1234;
$test2='test1';
echo $$test2; // echoes 1234
```

Or, to make it compatible with your system...

```
$nameofpage=substr($nameofpage,1); // remove dollar
echo $$nameofpage.'<br/>';
```

Comment: That's it - thank you.  I tried out the variable variable but forgot to remove the leading $

Answer (score 0):

If you only store variable name without $ you can use variable of variable feature of PHP

```
   echo $$nameofpage,'<br />';
```

can remove $ from input stored

```
 $nameofpage=substr( $nameofpage, 1 );
 echo $$nameofpage,'<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks Shakti.  As with Christian's comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're after evaluating the pages you've referenced, then this would work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT fld_pagename FROM tbl_pages WHERE fld_show = 1 ORDER BY fld_ref");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $nameofpage = $row['fld_pagename'];
    include($nameofpage);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this actually brings the whole page in rather than the name.

Answer (score -1):

it seems your database design is wrong.
There is not a single reason to store PHP variable names in the database.
Store pagenames itself and you'll be okay

Comment: Maybe he's trying to create some sort of template system... Such generalized arguments aren't constructive at all..

Comment: @Christian I have enough experience to judge it myself.

Comment: Well, I have enough experience to judge those that put a definite line between best practices or not.

Comment: @Christian best practices? what about separation data from code one, dude?

Comment: Exactly, it's not always best practice to do that. Templates are a living example of that. And really, if you try pointing out that at PHP devs, they can't but laugh at the notion, since PHP's objective is to do just that (albeit as nicely as possible).

Comment: Why do you use StackOverflow even? How can you know about wrong design when you know nothing about what the OP is doing?

Comment: Things I didn't say in the original post as I didn't want to make it too long:  This is a simple template site based around a MySQL database.  There are certain variables which I have set out away from the database on a single sheet of resources.  There are other ways of doing this.  I chose this way as it works for this site.

Comment: @Outerbridge not "other ways" but proper ways

Comment: There's no such thing as "proper way", there might be "better ways" though.

Comment: @Christian in your virtual world - may be. in the real world there are proper ways and improper ones. `echo "$nameofpage"` is an example of improper one.

Comment: As is `eval($_GET['e']);`, does this fact make my argument any better? As to my "virtual world", I have no idea what you're talking about. Perhaps you don't "twit" or "like" enough to know that I'm not part of it?